Azure-cli python related error with az login command
az login command from the azure cli current latest version (2.61.0) will result in error as follows in Windows Server 2016
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
ErrorTag: 540656077, ErrorCode: 0, ErrorContext: Caught exception, ErrorStatus: Response_Status.Status_Unexpected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 664, in execute
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 731, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 701, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 334, in __call__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 158, in login
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 172, in login
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/auth/identity.py", line 160, in login_with_auth_code
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py", line 1966, in acquire_token_interactive
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/application.py", line 2084, in _acquire_token_interactive_via_broker
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\msal/broker.py", line 202, in _signin_interactively
  File "pymsalruntime\PyMsalRuntime.pyx", line 261, in pymsalruntime.pymsalruntime.signin_interactively
  File "pymsalruntime\PyMsalRuntime.pyx", line 981, in pymsalruntime.pymsalruntime._check_error
RuntimeError: ErrorTag: 540656077, ErrorCode: 0, ErrorContext: Caught exception, ErrorStatus: Response_Status.Status_Unexpected
To check existing issues, please visit: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues

any ideas how can I check this further?

The error logs shows that it's a generic issue caused by the windows server when trying to execute az login command. Check below reasons as detailed.
Need to check below:
According to the MSDoc for signing in with WAM method, if there is any issue with the windows authentication method, set core.enable_broker_on_windows=false to disable the windows broker and try logging into the account again.
az config set core.enable_broker_on_windows=false

If you encounter an issue and want to revert to the previous browser-based authentication method, set the core.enable_broker_on_windows configuration property to false.

az login
Check the Az CLI version and upgrade it to avoid these kinds of conflicts.

Check that all dependencies like python and windows server are properly configured accordingly to the CLI version releases in your environment.
Try using --use-device-code parameter to provide an interactive authentication with Azure when logged in.
Also try logging into Azure with a service principal by providing AppID, Secret as follows.
az account set --subscription xxxx
az login --service-principal -u e4xxxx989 -p YxxxxvL --tenant <TenantID>
az account show


If still the issue persists, uninstall the current AzCLI from the windows server and reinstall it with the latest version.
Also refer here for the common Github CLI issues.
